# CKeditor doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a problem. I added CKeditor to my website.
Now i have a problem. If i add lines:

```
    <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'tresc' );
   </script>
```

In head section on my main page everything works, but if i go to contact or panel page unfortunetly editor doesn't work(name of the textarea is the same). If i add this lines at the end of body section in contant or panel works, but in the main page only one textarea working with editor, rest doesn't. Writing website on includes(my index is not changing and everything in content div is including from other files). Can some1 help me?

Comment: I reuploaded all files except config file. I also checked order of including in head page. Its look like this: <including ckeditor,js> then <ckeditor.replace>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation-section-adding-ckeditor-to-your-page

1. The `replace` method has to be used below `textarea` tag.
2. Your `textarea` tags need to have unique `id` and/or `name` attributes. So that each CKEditor instance knows to which textarea it is assigned. Unique element `id's` are also a requirement in HTML.
3. If your `textarea` tags can't have different `names` (they can't have same `id's`), please drop the `names` and assign fake class to each e.g. '`myeditor`' and use [replaceAll](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll) method:  `CKEDITOR.replaceAll('myeditor');`.

Comment: I've tried add class or id and then use "replaceAll". Nothing happening :(

Comment: `Id's` need to different for every `textarea`. You would need to either use `replace` method for each `textarea` or simply drop `id's` and use `CKEDITOR.replaceAll();` at the bottom of your page. Please also check your browser console as there might be some other JavaScript errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem.
I've added class and use another `<script></script>`. Now everything is working. Thanks j.swiderski for helping me. Best regards.